# How to control matplotlib figure.patch.facecolor changes when animating?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating an animated line plot using `matplotlib.animation`. I explicitly create a figure with a custom background color to go with the seaborn plot background color like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=3, figsize=(8, 13.5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#EAEAF2')
```

When plotting with `plt.show()`, the whole figure has a grey background color. However, when animating the line-plots, the figure background is the default white (the plot background inside the axis is still seaborn's grey). Here is the relevant animation code:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=3, figsize=(8, 13.5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#EAEAF2')

line, = ax[0].plot([], [])
vline = ax[0].axvline(x=5, color='gray')

def init():
    line.set_data(scales, [np.nan] * len(scales))
    return line, 

def update(i):
    y = data[i]
    line.set_data(scales, y)
    line.set_color(sns.cubehelix_palette(22)[i])
    vline.set_xdata([i + 6])
    return line, vline,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, interval=200, frames=22, blit=False)
ani.save('animation.gif')
```

Any ideas what is happening here? Why does the animator change the background color? How can I control the figure background color while animating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but saved images always have white background color, unless specified otherwise, like

```
ani.save('animation.gif', writer="imagemagick", savefig_kwargs=dict(facecolor='#EAEAF2'))
```